# Upgrading tesseract version on Kaggle

Tags: version, tesseract, kaggle

If I print the version of tesseract on my machine, I get:

```
tesseract version:  5.3.1.20230401
```

Here I am explicitly pointing to:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
```

I need to setup this same version on Kaggle.
Currently on Kaggle I get the following:

```
> !tesseract --version
tesseract 4.1.1
```

I have copied my entire tesseract folder onto Kaggle and tried to point towards it explicitly:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"/kaggle/input/tesseract-ocr/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"
```

However, I get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/kaggle/input/tesseract-ocr/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
```

If I don't explicitly point to it, I get the following, but don't know how to access this folder to copy my latest version tesseract.exe:

```
> # Check path to tesseract
!which tesseract
/usr/bin/tesseract
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the short answer is that Kaggle does not allow an executable (.exe) to be run from a user's input directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will not be able to run a Windows executable on Kaggle, as the underlying OS Kaggle uses is Linux-based; however, you can run Tesseract-OCR 5!

I've created a notebook you can reference/fork to get started:
[Working with Tesseract-OCR 5 on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/dhorvay/working-with-tesseract-ocr-5-on-kaggle)

The short of it is, just run this command at the top of your notebook.

```bash
!rm /opt/conda/lib/libcurl.so.4 
!ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.8.0 /opt/conda/lib/libcurl.so.4
!add-apt-repository ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr5 -y
!apt update
!apt install -y tesseract-ocr
!apt install tesseract-ocr-eng
# If you want all languages -- please note this will take time to download. You could also point to the already install tessdata in 4.00 as well.
# !apt install tesseract-ocr-all -y
!tesseract --version
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this on the next competition.